# Creating multiple files programmatically on Android through the Google Drive API often creates duplicates?

Tags: android, api, upload, duplicates, drive

I am trying to upload files from the internal storage to a user's Google Drive through the API, to back up user data. What I have done so far works on occasion, but it often creates two or three copies of the files as well and I have no idea why.

As far as I know there is no way to upload entire folders and their contents at once, so instead I first create an empty backup folder, then iterate through the user data and copy the files into the folder one by one.

Note: for now I am using the root folder of the Google Drive instead of the App folder that is dedicated for this purpose. This makes it easier to see the files that are created. When everything works, I'll swap the root folder with the app folder.

Creating a new backup first starts with looking for existing backup folders and deleting them if there are any:

```
private void createNewBackup(Context context, GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {

// Create query to search for existing backup folder
Query query = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "Backup"))
        .build();

Drive.getDriveResourceClient(context, googleSignInAccount).query(query)

// if a backup folder is found, delete it:
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<MetadataBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(MetadataBuffer metadata) {
            // there are never 2 backup folders, so it is always the first set of metadata, hence get(0).
            DriveFolder backupfolder = metadata.get(0).getDriveId().asDriveFolder();
            Drive.getDriveResourceClient(context, googleSignInAccount).delete(backupfolder)

            // when the folder is deleted, create a new backup folder
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    createBackupFolder(context, googleSignInAccount);
                }
            });
        }
    })
    // if no backup folder is found, create a new backup folder
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            createBackupFolder(context, googleSignInAccount);
        }
    });
}
```

When the old backup folder is deleted, this is the code that creates the new backup folder

```
public void createBackupFolder(Context context, GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {

// Get the root folder of the drive:
Drive.getDriveResourceClient(context, googleSignInAccount).getRootFolder().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveFolder>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(DriveFolder driveFolder) {
        // create backup folder in root folder:
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .setTitle("Backup")
                .setMimeType(DriveFolder.MIME_TYPE)
                .setStarred(true)
                .build();

        Log.d("Test", "Creating backup folder");
        Drive.getDriveResourceClient(context, googleSignInAccount).createFolder(driveFolder, changeSet)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveFolder>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DriveFolder backupFolder) {
                        Log.d("Test", "Created backup folder");
                        writeDataToBackupFolder(context, googleSignInAccount, backupFolder);
                    }
                })
                // if the folder couldn't be created:
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("Test", "failed to create backup folder");
                    }
                });
    }
});}
```

And then finally the files in the subfolders "premium" and "shifts" are copied to the backup folder on the drive with the writeDataToBackupFolder method:

```
public void writeDataToBackupFolder(Context context, GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount, DriveFolder backupFolder) {
// iterate over the files in the subfolders
File[] subfolders = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath()).listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < subfolders.length; i++) {

    if (subfolders[i].getName().equals("premium") || subfolders[i].getName().equals("shifts")) {

        File[] filesInSubfolder = new File(subfolders[i].getPath()).listFiles();

        for (int j = 0; j < filesInSubfolder.length; j++) {
            // for every file, get its contents and write them to a file and upload it to the drive

            String fileName = subfolders[i].getName() + "/" + filesInSubfolder[j].getName();

            List<String> content = readFromFile(context, fileName);

            Drive.getDriveResourceClient(context, googleSignInAccount).createContents().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveContents>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DriveContents driveContents) {
                    OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);

                    try {
                        for (int k = 0; k < content.size(); k++) {
                            writer.write(content.get(k));
                            writer.write("\n");
                        }
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle(fileName)
                            .setMimeType("text/plain")
                            .setStarred(true)
                            .build();

                    Log.d("Test", "Creating file "+fileName);
                    Drive.getDriveResourceClient(context, googleSignInAccount).createFile(backupFolder, changeSet, driveContents)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DriveFile>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DriveFile driveFile) {
                                    Log.d("Test", "Created file "+fileName);
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Log.d("Test", "Failed to create "+fileName);
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}}
```

It deletes the old backup folder and creates the new backup folder just fine and it always copies the files to the Google Drive. They are all text files, but sometimes (more often than not) duplicates are created. For example, the folder 'premium' has files 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, etc., but on the drive they would appear as premium/1.txt, premium/1.txt, premium/2.txt, premium/3.txt, premium/3.txt, and I have no idea why. Which files become duplicates is random and can change everytime I call the createNewBackup method. As you can see in the code, I register created files in the log, but no duplicates show up there, only on the Drive. Is it a problem with the Google Drive API? Am I calling everything too quickly? How could I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. Even though the duplicates problem has not been solved yet, it does not really pose a problem, because when I restore a backup, all the user files are overwritten, so it does not matter if that happens once or twice extra.